# Improve counting algorithm performance

Tags: java, performance, java-stream

I need to write algorithm that will take 2 collections, `List<String>` and `MyClass[]`

```
public class MyClass {
   String key;
   String value;
}
```

Then it will iterate over `MyClass[]` and check if its `key` is also in `List<String>`. It can't be simple `contains` here, `key` has 2 parts, text and number (for example "Lorem ipsum 1990", we need to check only text part so here comes `trimNumber` method.

```
 public String trimNumber(String key) {           
       String[] splitKey = key.split(" ");
       return splitKey [splitKey .length-1].matches(("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) ?
       key.replace(splitKey [splitKey .length-1], "").trim() : key;
    }
```

Now, I need to count each occurence of this match.
Last step, is to find the highest occurence from whole collection.

And finally, my implementation of this

```
public long calculate(final List<String> list, final MyClass[] data) {
        return Arrays.stream(data)
                .map(MyClass::getKey)
                .map(Main::trimNumber)
                .filter(list::contains)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v -> v, Collectors.counting()))
                .values()
                .stream()
                .mapToLong(i -> i)
                .max()
                .orElse(1);
    }
```

Now the problem is, can I simplify that? Or change something so perfromance is better? That piece is just one part of bigger algorithm, that will operate on large amount of data. Lets say 15 000 x `MyClass[150]` per one HTTP request. So each second counts here.

Comment: List.contains() is O(N). Transform it to a HashSet first. HashSet.contains() is O(1).

Comment: Replace you `trimNumber` implementation with `return key.replaceFirst(" ?+\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$", "");`, that's already using a regex, it's already returning the original string when there's no match, and by prepending `" ?+"` and appending `$`, it will be restricted to the last space-separated term, if there are spaces. No need for `split`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `List<String>` to hold the `key` we can use a `Set<String>` specifically the `HashSet<String>` implementation for the key look up. Internally the `HashSet` will use a backing `HashMap` to store the data as the key of the `HashMap`.

Now usually the lookup time of the key is `O(1)` in the best case assuming no hash collisions but in case there are the look up time would be at most `O(log(n))` from JDK-8 onwards, this is because internally the linked chain of entries from the hash collisions are transformed to a **LinkedList** to a **Red-Black** tree where the look up time is logarithmic through a treeify process.

This is the JEP for the above change:

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180

This article has made a benchmark test to show the comparison between the `contains` method of an `ArrayList` and a `HashSet`:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashset-arraylist-contains-performance

And if possible we can store the trimmed text of the key in another filed of the `MyClass` class so `Main::trimNumber` call is not made for all requests but that will also translate to an extra memory overhead:

```
public class MyClass {
   String key;
   String value;
   String trimmedKey; //caching the trimmed key value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see several issues in your snippet.

---

**First.** You use `Regular Expression`. This is pretty slow in general. So you have to use `Matcher` with a precompiling regular expression or even avoid using it. E.g. like this one:

```
private static final Function<String, String> trimNumber = key -> {
    for (int i = key.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        char ch = key.charAt(i);

        if (ch == ' ')
            return key.substring(0, i);
        if (ch < '0' || ch > '9')
            return key.substring(0, i + 1);
    }

    return "";
};
```

For simple string part, it's easier to use `for loop`. It works much better than regular expression.

Moreover, `String` in Java is immutable, so when you want to substrate a part of a string, it's better to use `str.substract()` instead of `str.replace("")`.

---

**Second.** You use `List` for keys cache. It's much better to use `Set` to have *O(1)* performance.

---

I think your solution could look like this one:

```
public static long calculate(Set<String> keys, MyClass[] data) {
    Map<String, Long> map = Arrays.stream(data)
                                  .map(MyClass::getKey)
                                  .map(trimNumber)
                                  .filter(keys::contains)
                                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v -> v, Collectors.counting()));

    return map.values().stream().mapToLong(i -> i).max().orElse(1L);
}
```